# How to use the WHERE clause in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

The "a.form" condition in the WHERE clause is not being met in the following query. That's regardless of whatever form that is used, for example, even if form=1 all students of economics in form 4 are displayed as result of the query.

```
SELECT a.Form, 
       c.AcademicYear, 
       b.SubjectName, 
       b.UserID, 
       b.Password, 
       c.* 
FROM   StudentDetails.Programmes a, 
       StudentDetails.Subjects b, 
       RegistrationDetails.Registration c 
WHERE  b.SubjectName = 'Economics' 
       AND b.UserID = 'user' 
       AND b.Password = 'user' 
       AND c.Term = 1 
       AND c.academicyear = '2011/2012' 
       AND a.form = 1 
       AND ( core1 = 'Economics' 
              OR core2 = 'Economics' 
              OR core3 = 'Economics' 
              OR core4 = 'Economics' 
              OR elec1 = 'Economics' 
              OR elec2 = 'Economics' 
              OR elec3 = 'Economics' 
              OR elec4 = 'Economics' )
```

Comment: you are not joining your tables using JOIN statements, you are selecting everything from every table in your FROM clause.  As a result, it is only filtering items in the form table, not the other tables according to the form relationship.

Answer (score 4):

you should use the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.name = TableB.name
```

It will be alot clearer for you and it is the better syntax.

Have you no logical table relationships?

Please go to this site it will really help you,
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html